# A question about $[X,Y]$, where $X,Y$ are vector fields

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Here we set $X,Y\in \Gamma(TM)$, $f\in C^\infty(M)$, $q\in M$. Then when we consider $[X,Y]$ as the derivation, what is $[X,Y](f)(q)$? Is that $X_qY_q(f)-Y_qX_q(f)$?

Comment: $X_q(Y_q(f))$ doesn't make sense, because $Y_q(f)$ is just a number. You want $X_q(Yf)$, because you need something defined in a neighborhood of $q$ to plug into $X_q$.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you, but what is Yf? Y could only acts on the points of M, but f is not a point.

Comment: $Yf$ is the function $q \mapsto Y_qf$. It's shorthand. One way to think about it is that while tangent vectors take (germs of) functions in a neighborhood of a point and spit out a number, vector *fields* take functions and spit out new functions.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you!